# Cross compile to Linux from Windows using cmake and custom toolchain

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I want to compile grpc libraries for Linux x86_64 target from Windows 64-bit host and using custom tool chain for cross-platform provided by Unreal Engine team.

here is my toolchain file (what I think are related)

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)
set(LINUX_ARCH_NAME "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")

set(CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/${LINUX_ARCH_NAME}")
set(CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_BIN "${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "${LINUX_ARCH_NAME}")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(COMPILER_FLAGS       " -nostdinc++ --target=${LINUX_ARCH_NAME} --sysroot='${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}' -fno-math-errno -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -funwind-tables -gdwarf-3")
set(FLAGS_DEBUG          " -O0 -g -D_DEBUG")
set(FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     " -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(FLAGS_RELEASE        " -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO " -O3 -g -D_DEBUG")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH "")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "")
```

and here is my build command

```
cmake -G "Ninja Multi-Config" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="./for_linux.cmake" ..
```

it success without any error

and then when I try build

```
cmake --build .
```

some codes are compiled successfully but some failed because it include host environment's headers (like Windows Kit or MSVC)

```
C:/Toolchains/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang.exe -I... -I.... -IC:/Toolchains/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/include -I.... -I....
(there is no path to MSVC or Windows Kit in -I args)
```

```
C:/Toolchains/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/include/stdint.h:122:27: error: typedef redefined with different types ('unsigned long' vs 'unsinged long long')
typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t;
                          ^
C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/include/vadefs.h:61:35: note: previous definition is here
typedef unsigned __int64 uintptr_t;
                         ^
```

I can't understand why clang use those MSVC headers for it.
I assumed `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)` option prevents problem like this and execution command seems not include MSVC path.

and it seems that clang compile codes with _WIN64 macro too.

I tried some options with googling like set CMAKE_SYSROOT to toolchain path. but nothing changed.

did I miss some options?

Answer (score 2):

Self answer.

the problem was`--sysroot='${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}'` in following setting.

```
set(COMPILER_FLAGS " -nostdinc++ --target=${LINUX_ARCH_NAME} --sysroot='${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}' -fno-math-errno -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -funwind-tables -gdwarf-3")
or
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT})
```

I don't know about detail but it seems like I have been should set sysroot to `--sysroot='${CLANG_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/usr'` when using linux toolchain that provided by UnrealEngine.

(`${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/include` has nested sub-directories to reach actual headers while `${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/usr/include` is not)

now I have different errors but this problem is solved.